# remove # from the end of http://localhost:4200

Tags: angular, angularjs

How to remove the # sign from the angular application i.e. http://localhost:4200/#/

it was in angular application. http://localhost:4200/#/

Answer (score 1):

Your app is using the [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy).

You probably have in your code base something like :

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

which can be remove entirely as `PathLocationStrategy` is the default value

or

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Then you just have to remove the `useHash` option.